# How do i make "go get" look in the web rather than on my computer

Tags: go

I"m trying to contribute for a project and the docs tell me to use this command

```
go get github.com/foo/bar
```

but the error is

```
can't load package: package github.com/foo/bar: no Go files in /home/f/go/src/github.com/foo/bar
```

Obviously its looking on my computer but how do I make it so that it downloads from the web?

Comment: What's your Go version? Mine doesn't do that, it tries immediately to download from github. Also, make sure you have `git` installed?

Comment: go version gives go1.12.7 linux/amd64

Comment: and you have `git` installed?

Comment: yup git version 2.17.1

Comment: post the output of `go get -v github.com/foo/bar`

Comment: `github.com/foo/bar (download)
# cd .; git clone https://github.com/foo/bar /home/f/go/src/github.com/foo/bar
Cloning into '/home/f/go/src/github.com/foo/bar'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
package github.com/foo/bar: exit status 128`

Comment: the package i want to actually download is dnote `go get github.com/dnote/dnote`

Comment: Can you provide a link to the actual repository you're having problems with? According to that output, it _is_ trying to download, but is failing for some reason. Not sure if this `dnote` thing is having the same issue, get to that in a second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196671/discussion-between-francis-chang-and-ocket8888).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the project you're trying to download cannot be built, because Go can't find any source files to build at the source path `github.com/foo/bar`. The package **is**, however, downloaded, and if you look in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/foo/bar` you will see the repository cloned there. So if you want just that, then you're done, but you can use `go get -d` in the future to avoid the error message.

If you want something specific that can be imported, e.g. `github.com/foo/bar/somepackage`, then you should use `go get github.com/foo/bar/somepackage`.